# Combine Images in Canvas and then view it through ImageView using Android Studio

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

I want to combine images by putting them on top of eachother in Canvas and then view the combination using ImageView. What I know is if you set the first Bitmap into the Canvas everything else you do will be added to that first Bitmap. I only get the error:
PointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

```
ImageView mainImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
    Bitmap bottomImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("image1.png");
    Bitmap topImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("image2.png");

    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bottomImage.getWidth(), bottomImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bottomImage, 0, 0, null);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(topImage, 0, 0, null);

    mainImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code

```
public Bitmap drawImageOnImage(Bitmap background, Bitmap pic, int x_to_draw, int y_to_draw, int width, int height)
{
    try
    {
        Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(background);
        Bitmap img_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pic, width, height, true);
        newCanvas.drawBitmap(img_bitmap, x_to_draw, y_to_draw,new Paint());

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Occured=>");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return background;
}
```

Here function takes 2 input bitmaps, Background bitmap and another image bitmap to draw over background bitmap. You will get combined bitmap to set for ImageView. X and Y are the co-rdinates where top image bitmap start paint. Same for height and width

Comment: I tried but the top picture did not show. But I figured another way.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments this code worked perfectly. And I added multiple top images.

```
private void drawAndView(ImageView imgView, Bitmap bottomImage, Bitmap[] topImages){
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bottomImage.getWidth(), bottomImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bottomImage, 0, 0, null);
    for (Bitmap bitmap : topImages){
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    imgView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
}
```